# add page number to EVERY page footer

Tags: libreoffice

`Insert -> Fields -> Page number` only adds page number at the cursor. How can I add page number every page footer in LibreOffice 3.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must, first, select the footer. Then do the Insert -> Fields -> Page Number.
I Hope it helps.

Comment: could you describe "select the footer"? I double clicked the footer, seems that every footer is selected. But still page number is only added to the cursor place. Thx.

Comment: When you click the footer, a message will appear "Footer (default style)" and a plus sign next of it. Click that plus sign and you will have the cursor in the footer